# Is using 'ch' for CSS widths appropriate?

Tags: css, fonts, width, scale, font-size

For anything involving width units in CSS, I've always used **px** when I need fixed widths and **em** when I need widths relative to the size of the font.

Then I realized **em** really is a measurement of the *height* of the font, not the *width*.  Thus **ch** seems much more appropriate.

Ignoring that **ch** is a relatively new CSS unit (older browsers may not support it), when specifying any horizontal length that should scale with the size of the font, is it best to use **ch**, **em**, or something else?

Comment: In researching the 'em' unit, I find much conflicting information as to whether it is ONLY a measurement of height or if it reflects both the height and width of the font.  Either way, the 'ch' unit seems like a better choice for widths, but I cannot find any references to support that hypothesis.

Answer (score 3):

Don't think of `em` in terms of height or width of the font, it's derived from a font's metrics metadata and is technically in no way related to individual letters in the font, or even the average height or width of a specific set of letters. It's simply a value that you know is always the same no matter where you load that font, which is why it's fine to use *as long as you make sure to load the correct font*.

If you specify which font to use, you can safely use `em` and know your content is always sized the same no matter which device/browser combination is used. On the other hand, if you leave any of the fonts used implied (like relying on system names or using "serif" or even simply never specifying the topmost font for `<html>` or `<body>`) then you'll have to think twice about using `em`, or indeed any relative unit.

Bottom line: enforce the fonts on your page(s), and then `em` units are 100% reliable, because the fonts used in each contexts are always guaranteed to be the ones you designed against.

**Update:** CSS3 came out about 2 years after this answer which redefined what an `em` means. Under current rules (April 2017) `em` are defined as the same value as `font-size`. As such, a `font-size: 16px` straight-up means that `1em` corresponds to `16px`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your contribution.  Do you have a definitive (and current) reference for your answer?  When I research the issue online, I find a significant amount of conflicting information.  About half state what you are stating, and half state the opposite.  You use the words 'technically in no way', which makes me think you found a better reference.  Thanks.

Comment: The point I was trying to make is that it is irrelevant whether it's about the height or width: so as long as you ensure you use `em` with an explicitly specific font, that combination will always do the same thing. The [CSS Level 1](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS1/#units) specification notes that `em` is the font's height, but that's it: 1em for different fonts at the same point size can differ: a tiny font can specify a massive height, to effect a large baseline-to-baseline distance, and similarly a large font can specify a height that's less than its ascenders, effecting vertical overlap.

Comment: The original answer here is actually incorrect. In CSS, an em is a relative size but is independent of the font family chosen. The CSS specification is that an em is always equal to the font-size. So 1em on an element that is "font-size: 12px" is 12 pixels in length; whereas ex and ch are contextual to the font family chosen. Source: https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#font-relative-lengths

Comment: updated the answer to include this new-due-to-spec-changes-after-this-answer information =)